# How to create loader filling dots background as animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Here is the img.]

Dots on this img should be filling background. Only jquery animation. How to create this? Canvas? Any ideas?

Comment: Неясная , что вы просите ... This is english website

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderPechkarev/o10yhn56/10/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=o10yhn56), simply change your logic by defining how and when to change opacity.

CSS

```
    .circleBase {
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  opacity: 0;
  // filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.type1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.type2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.type3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: aqua;
  border: 30px solid blue;
}
```

JS

```
    $('.circleBase').each(function(index){

    // add your opacity logic here - when and how to change it
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).fadeTo('slow', 0.8);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="circleBase type1"></div>

<div class="circleBase type2"></div>
<div class="circleBase type2"></div>

<div class="circleBase type3"></div>
```